# Identification and maintenance of cutting board counter

Tags: wood, cutting-board

Our place has a cutting board built into the countertop by the stove. We've been using it as a cutting board, but someone pointed out to me that I need to make sure it's unfinished (for safety) and that it requires proper maintenance.

How can I tell if it's safe to use for food? It looks like a normal cutting board to me, but I'm not experienced in the matter.

Looking up maintenance, sources said it depends on the kind of wood. Comparing to pictures it appears it could be maple (which is also common), but again, I am inexperienced in this regard.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You do not have to ensure this is unfinished for food safety. Many products used for direct food contact and for prep work have some finish applied.

Comment: Wood IDs are off-topic for this SE, but I am pretty certain what you have there is made of a cross-lamination of bamboo.

Answer (score 2):

Because its a cutting board, you could scrape it with a razor blade, if any finish comes up, its finished. From the pictures it looks clearly unfinished.

I also agree with one of the comments that this is bamboo, which needs less maintenance than some woods. A regular (monthly) oiling with mineral oil would be a standard thing to do.

Otherwise it looks great, practical, and I recommend that you enjoy using it.